# Remove data between brackets in Coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Using Coldfusion I am trying to remove all data between brackets and add a colon to identify a break in the data.  Below is an example of the string

[FIRE] A16 - check up to underage juvn in one of the cars  [05/01/21 19:07:31 LENDOWS]
NO TO COVID QUESTIONS FOR CALLER  [05/01/21 18:57:21 JJONES]
one car not driveable, other party says they don`t have insurance info  [05/01/21 18:55:55 JJONES] [FIRE] refusal obtained

In the end it would look like:

A16 - check up to underage juvn in one of the cars: NO TO COVID QUESTIONS FOR CALLER : one car not driveable, other party says they don`t have insurance info : refusal obtained :

Comment: I'm not sure of the code but I think you need to first do a `ReReplace` to replace the part between the brackets with an empty string, and then use `Replace` on the brackets..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Regular Expression you want is `\[.*?\]`.

```
<cfset str = "[FIRE] A16 - check up to underage juvn in one of the cars 
[05/01/21 19:07:31 LENDOWS] NO TO COVID QUESTIONS FOR CALLER [05/01/21 
18:57:21 JJONES] one car not driveable, other party says they don`t have 
insurance info [05/01/21 18:55:55 JJONES] [FIRE] refusal obtained">

<cfset newStr = reReplace(str, "\[.*?\]", ":", "ALL")>

<cfoutput>#newStr#</cfoutput>
```

This will output exactly what you asked for, replace `[*]` with `:` .

```
: A16 - check up to underage juvn in one of the cars : NO TO COVID QUESTIONS
 FOR CALLER : one car not driveable, other party says they don`t have 
insurance info : : refusal obtained
```

Notice that you have a leading `:` and a couple of doubles where there were two sets of bracketed text following each other. You can clean up the text from here.